# Calculating intensity of a 0...1 scale

Tags: spatial-statistics, density

I'm trying to come up with the Intensity value for the Cells dataset ([Diggle 1983](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~pcaragea/S40608/Notes/PointPatterns/PP_intro.pdf#page=3)). This dataset has coordinates from 0 to 1, probably percent, there is no actual unit to it as I think it was taken from bugs or something.

What tool should I use to calculate the intensity of the layer? I looked at Point density but that produces a 'raster' and I am looking for just a single value.

I'm new to ArcGIS.

Comment: Since you're looking for a single value, your concept of intensity might differ from other common uses of the word.  Could you elaborate on what this number is intended to represent?  If it means the count of points per unit area, why not divide the count of points by the area?